# Search and replace RegExp Affecting Parts of Words

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, search, replace

So I have a script that searches fro an array of words from my list and then turns them into links with the same class as the word, but the problem is it is changing parts of words as well. so my **once** becomes **on**ce with my script. On, he, a, an, and the like are screwing up a lot of words. how do I make it only affect the whole words?

```
var words = ['able','about','after','all','along','an','and','arrived','as','asked','at','ate','attacked','baby','back','bad','baddies','be','became','before','Behind','being','big','biting','boat','borrowed','boy','boys','burst','by','came','care','causing','children','chores','collect','come','common','continued','couple','cut','dango','day','decided','demon','demons','did','did','difficult','do','dog','doing','eat','energy','enjoy','even','ever','everyone','evil','farewell','fight','find','firewood','floating','for','found','friends','from','gate','gave','gift','give','go','God','gold','got','green','grew','guessed','guys','had','happily','have','he','He','heard','help','her','him','his','home','houses','However','husband','in','including','into','is','island','it','Japan','Japanese','joined','journey','keep','lady','large','laundry','left','lived','looked','lot','lots','man','mean','met','momo','Momotaro','monkey','more','mountain','much','name','no','not','of','off','ogres','old','on','Once','One','open','out','own','pain','path','peach','pecking','people','pheasant','power','problems','quest','quickly','ran','real','red','returned','river','said','sailed','saw','screamed','see','seen','sell','set','She','shock','smashed','so','some','soon','special','spotted','stayed','stolen','stop','story','strong','surprised','take','Taro','tasty','terrible','terrorising','that','The','their','them','there','they','things','this','though','thought','through','time','to','too','took','up','upon','used','Using','village','walked','was','way','were','When','where','which','while','with','woman','work','would','you'],

    reg = new RegExp('(' + words.join('|') + ')', 'g');

    jQuery('.thestory').html(function (_, curHtml) {
        return curHtml.replace(reg, "<a href='#' class='$1'>$1</a>");
    });
```

Thanks for your help m(-_-)m

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\b` denotes a word boundary, so:

```
var reg = new RegExp('\\b(' + words.join('|') + ')\\b', 'g');
```